# How the messages are serialized between multiple WndProcs?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, message

I created two WndProcs in the main thread and then I post a messages from other threads to each of them, almost at the same time, but starting with WndProc1. This WndProc1 has a job to do which lasts for some time... It sigals when it begins and when it ends. WndProc2 also signal when is accessed. Now, when I press the button to start this test, I get: "P1-Enter ... [delay] ... P1-Leave WndProc2". As you can see, the second message waits for WndProc1 to finish, although he was sent to to WndProc2 ! What I want to know is how this serialization works if those two WndProcs have nothing in common ? I think that even happens if I have two different components, each with his own WndProc (but I didn't check).

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, SyncObjs;

type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FHnd: HWND;
    FTime: Integer;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AHnd: HWND; ATime: Integer);
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    TestHand1, TestHand2: HWND;
    MyT1, MyT2: TMyThread;
  protected
    procedure TestWndProc1(var Msg: TMessage);
    procedure TestWndProc2(var Msg: TMessage);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMyThread.Create(AHnd: HWND; ATime: Integer);
begin
 inherited Create;
 FHnd:= AHnd;
 FTime:= ATime;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
 Sleep(FTime);
 PostMessage(FHnd, WM_USER, 0, 0);
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TestHand1:= AllocateHWnd(TestWndProc1);
 TestHand2:= AllocateHWnd(TestWndProc2);
end;

procedure TForm1.TestWndProc1(var Msg: TMessage);
var I: Integer;
    A, B, C: Cardinal;
begin
 if Msg.Msg = WM_USER then begin
  Caption:= Caption + '  P1-Enter';
  A:= $12345678; B:= $98765432;
  for I:= 1 to 180000000 do begin
   C:= A * B; B:= C * A; A:= B * C;
  end;
  Caption:= Caption + '  P1-Leave';
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TestWndProc2(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
 if Msg.Msg = WM_USER then
  Caption:= Caption + '  WndProc2';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Caption:= '';
 MyT1:= TMyThread.Create(TestHand1, 300);
 MyT2:= TMyThread.Create(TestHand2, 350);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Indeed messages are retrieved from the message queue one by one. The message you posted later won't be retrieved and processed until the one you posted earlier is processed. As you can see, different window procedures or different components, what they have common is the message queue - they live in the same thread and hence share the same queue.

Comment: But that's what I don't understand... How can two window procedures (or more) have the same mesage queue ?

Comment: A message queue is a feature of a thread not a window. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#queued-messages).

Comment: Not sure if it's obvious, you create different threads but those different threads are posting to the same (main/gui) thread (because the windows they post to are created by the main thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is perfectly expected. Each thread has one and only one message queue and may have zero to many window handles. Window handles usually correspond to visual components but not necessarily as in your example.

Somewhere in the code (for a GUI in Delphi, this is in the *Forms* unit), there is a so called "message loop" which retrieves messages from the queue and dispatches them to the corresponding `WndProc`. The dispatch mechanism is like a simple function call: it is blocking while a message is being processed, unless the message handler calls the message pump again (where [reentrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) problems start, if not handled correctly). Look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues) and look in the *Forms* unit for `TApplication.ProcessMessages` and in the *Classes* unit for `AllocateHWnd`/`DeallocateHWnd`.

If you want to execute code in parallel you must create separate threads; each one will execute in parallel as long as there are fewer threads than CPU cores and threads are not blocked by I/O or mutexes, semaphores and critical sections. If too many threads are ready to execute they are scheduled using preemptive multitasking.

You can communicate between threads using messages. For that, a thread must create a window handle and have a message pump.

In Delphi, the GUI can only be accessed from the main thread. If a secondary thread has something to display then it must let the display code execute by the main thread, most likely again through a message between the secondary/worker thread and main thread, or use the `Synchronize` method, or use other communication mechanisms such as pipes, sockets, file I/O, shared memory. Alone or in combination.

Comment: I don't want the code to be executed in parallel, in fact that's what I want to avoid. :) And I wanted to make sure that posting messages to multiple windows of the same thread is thread safe. Thanks for the good explanation ! If you allow me one more question, when I use `AllocateHwnd` to create a new window, how do I know for which thread is created ?

Comment: Please open a new question instead of asking in a comment. AllocateHwnd work in the context of the calling thread.